How can I use Android intents to make redirect URI to my app?
I am trying to make a basic custom POS app with Paypal Zettle android SDK and I am starting with their example app (https://github.com/iZettle/sdk-android/tree/master/Examples/Example-Java).
I need to set up a redirect URI that takes me back to the app after going into the browser to authenticate via OAuth.
I tried making intents in the manifest like:
<intent-filter>
  <data android:host="test"
      android:scheme="project-scheme"/>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>

I have tried testing this to see if it opens the app (by making an html file with a clickable link) but nothing happens when I click the link.
What else do I need to do to set up an intent that will open the app when I go to the redirect URI? (Also, if there is a way to set up this intent so that it works for specific HTTP urls that would be very appreciated)

Here is an example of how to make your app support deeplink :
<activity
     android:name=".SecondActivity"
     android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="www.mylocalapp.com" />
            <data android:pathPrefix="/view/secondActivity/" />
         </intent-filter>
</activity>


You need to set exported property to true, so that other apps can open your app.
Set autoVerify property to true, so that the link can be verified.
Use scheme as http and https to support http urls.
Use host to define base url.
Use pathPrefix for endpoints of url.

Note : The link is not automatically supported unless it is released on Playstore. To support deeplinks in debug apps. Follow the steps :

Go to app info of your app.
Click Defaults
Turn on Open Supported links.
Click Supported web addresses.
The base url you specified in the intent should be visible here, so turn it on.

 
